# ruby gem naming convention

Tags: ruby, rubygems, naming-conventions

I was feeling adventurous uploading a very basic ruby gem.  So I did not use the same name for the main `dir` that I did for the `lib subdir`.

So the architecture the gem dir is:

```
% tree
foo
    lib
        foo_bar.rb
        foo_bar_klass.rb
    foo_bar.gemspec
    foo_bar-0.0.1.gem
```

My `foo_bar.rb` file contains `require './foo_bar_klass.rb'`

In my `foo_bar.gemspec`

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s| 
    ...
    s.files = ['lib/foo_bar.rb','lib/foo_bar_klass.rb']
    ...
end
```

This is a very basic gemspec and the `push` was `successful`.

The reason I did this is because I am trying to understand the 'engineering' logic behind what exactly gets uploaded in a gem.  **It seems that `s.files`, and other gemspec variables, determines the contents of a gem.  So is naming the main dir (aka tree) the same as the .rb file in lib simply a naming convention?**   I haven't quite found this answer yet.

**Is there any consequence to naming `% tree` differently from the rb files in `lib`?**

Comment: This is a really odd structure. Why is there a file with `_klass.rb` at the end? Usually class definitions for `Example` go inside `example.rb` where additional functionality may be *mixed in* from modules with the same naming convention applied. It's not clear what you mean by `% tree` as that's not shown in the list, and `%` isn't meaningful.

Comment: It's worth reading the [Bundler guide to building Ruby gems](https://bundler.io/v1.12/guides/creating_gem.html) to get some ideas on how this is done conventionally.

Comment: You've set yourself up for pain. If a file is added, you will need to remember to manually update your s.files. Failing to do so will release a broken gem with no indication as to the problem. Please, stick to conventional gem structures. Be creative and innovative in what your gems DO!

Comment: @tadman `_klass.rb` just bc I want to get in the habit of separating classes (Objects) code from my user interaction code.  It makes debugging a bit easier I find.  I'm trying to avoid Bundler and Rake for now, so that I can drill down on the basics. That way I can use Bundler/Rake Rails/Sinatra for more complex apps.

Comment: @PeterCamilleri I'm all ears but can you please elaborate on what the conventions are (understand I'm trying)...my basis for gemspecs comes from rubygems guide and elexedwards.net right now

Comment: Really not sure what purpose that serves. If I'm opening your gem I want to see the code, and if you go out of your way to hide it that's just plain annoying. I'd suggest using proper object-oriented [Design Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) such as [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) instead of arbitrarily squirrelling away your implementations in oddly named files.

Comment: @tadman by `tree` I simply mean the main `dir` in this case `foo`...I'll make that change in the post

Comment: In all honesty, Bundler and Rake *are* the basics. Bundler is the de-facto way to manage gem installations, and Rake is the go-to tool for making "Makefile"-style build scripts. If you're skipping these you're going back in time to the 1990s when these tools weren't available and the Ruby experience was a lot more...primitive.

Comment: Remember the [`.gemspec` format is fully documented](https://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/). While you can construct these files by hand, you'll need *some* automation for anything but the most trivial gem. Sometimes this automation comes from leveraging the fact that a `.gempec` is Ruby code so you can do things like `git ls-files` in the script to pull in a list of dependencies automatically.

Comment: Ok.  I have the gems for both so I can look into applying them.  I'm just having a blast uploading on rubygems and seeing my gem downloaded! ;)

Comment: It's a real treat to see that, yeah! If you're writing public code, consider using something like [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.com) to verify that your gem tests okay before going live with a release. That's free for a public gem. That tool can be configured to test that your gem works on more than one version of Ruby, going back as far as you want, and other dependency versions, if any.

Comment: @tadman Actually I found TravisCI rather intimidating esp. its repo so I've sort of avoiding the testing my gems altogether...it's something I have to work my way up to

Comment: It may be a bit daunting at first, but in practice you just create a [`.travis.yml` file](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/ruby/) and Travis takes care of the rest. That's a great way to shake out "oh, right" bugs where it *Works On My Machine™* but not on anyone else's because of some simple mistake or mistaken assumption.

Comment: People much smarter than me will point you to Bundler and Rake. I always build my gems with Bundler, even if I make some small changes for features I don't use. My opinions on this matter are contained in my gem called make_gem. I make no claims of suitability for any use case but my own.